# Configuration properties file in Android project

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Where can I place configuration file in Android project? Currently I am made a directory in res directory as : 
**res/config/configuration.properties**

```
and want to access it as :
properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("config/configuration.properties"));
```

It is not working : input stream is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in **assets** directory as **assets/configuration.properties**

Example code

```
try {
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("configuration.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(is);

    String value = props.getProperty("key", "");

    is.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: there is no asset directory in my project. Just adding a directory with name assets under main, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Folder structure android config file]

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
properties.getProperty(key);
```