# Can't store and load Properties

Tags: java, android, properties

I'm trying to store my Properties-Object and load it again.
There is no exception on storing, but when I try to load and read it, it seems  to be empty.

Here you have the code i'm using to store:

```
public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //[...]
    private String filename = "config.properties"; //config-savePath
    private HashMap<String, String> someMap= new HashMap<>(); 
    someMap.put("SOME_KEY", "myValue");

    try{  //try to store and log (seems to work)
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(someMap);

        Log.v("===INFO===","List all Properties:");
        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
                Log.v("===INFO===","Property :" + key + " = " + properties.get(key).toString());
        }

        properties.store(getAssets().openFd(filename).createOutputStream(), null);
        Log.v("===INFO===","storing information successfully");
    }catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"- Error -\n information could not be stored",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("===ERR===", "Cert-Info could not be stored -fileNotFound-" + e.toString());
    }
```

Here you have the code I'm using to load (for Dev-reasons I execute it directly after storing):

```
    try{  //try to load and log
        Log.v("===INFO===","Try loading Properties after storing");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(getBaseContext().getAssets().open(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE));

        if (properties.isEmpty()){
            Log.v("===ERR===", "Properties is empty");
        }else{
            for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
                Log.v("===INFO===","Property :" + key + " = " + properties.get(key).toString());
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.v("===ERR===", "Properties could not be loaded" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}//end oncreate //end class
```

When I execute the code I get these Logs:

```
09-19 15:01:18.172 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===INFO===: List all Properties:
09-19 15:01:18.173 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===INFO===: Property :SOME_KEY = myValue
09-19 15:01:18.176 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===INFO===: storing information successfully
09-19 15:01:18.176 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===INFO===: Try loading Properties after storing
09-19 15:01:18.177 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===ERR===: Properties is empty
```

So as you can see, the loaded Property is empty. I have no idea why.
I would expect something like this instead of the error:

```
09-19 15:01:18.177 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===INFO===: Try loading Properties after storing
09-19 15:01:18.178 31242-31242/com.example.myapplication V/===INFO===: Property :SOME_KEY = myValue
```

It doesn't work, and was not able to find a compareable problem here.

If you like to copy and paste my code to androidStudio, please do the necessary Imports (auto-gen) and add a "assets"-folder with a "config.properties"-file to your Project-directory.
Hope you guys can help me!

**EDIT:** I`ve placed a config.properties File *with content* in the assets-Folder. Now Loading works fine, but I recive this error on storing:

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more quickly if you provide a [mcve]. You should provide enough code that anyone can copy/paste and then compile and run your code and get the exact same results which you are asking about.

Comment: The code is already a minimal complete snippet. A c+p is possible, if the user does the suggessted imports, creats the "asserts" directory an the "config.properties" File in there.

Comment: The code you here gives compile errors because there is no class. Therefore, it is not complete.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. You are right. I enjoy the compfort of AndroidStudio where you will get a prepared class =). I will edit the post for you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I could figure out the problem.
It is depending on the "Asserts"-Folder - it is a simple **Read-Only**-problem. 
Answered here: [Is Asset folder read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562904/is-asset-folder-read-only)

This is why "load" works fine, but "store" does not.
It seems that **there is no exception thrown if you try to write to an empty .property file**, even if it should (it won't work either).

A common work-around is using the [Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) instead of the asserts-folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
  HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Option 1:
     Properties prop = new Properties();
     prop.setProperty("SOME_KEY", "myValue");


Option2 :
     mymap.put("1", "test");
     mymap.put("2", "test2");
     prop.putAll(mymap);
     prop.store(new FileOutputStream("config.properties"),"");


Please refer to following link
    https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/
```

Comment: I don't think that that is an error:
If I'm not totaly wrong i can set multiple properties from a HashMap by using `prop.putAll(someHashMap)`
As you can see in the log-file, the properties-object contains the key-value-pair correctly before storing.
or did you mean s.th. else?

Comment: Update my answer please cross check

Comment: **Option 1** is not relevant for my app, and has no impact on my problem.
**Option 2** will give an `java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)` exception because in android Properties have to be accessed via `getAssets().openFd(filename).createOutputStream()`
**refer link** -I found this link too, i going to try it if nobody can say why my try does not work.
**Anyway** I'm realy grateful that you try to help me

Comment: Hi Terik You need to give the path of config properties where you have in your machine like assume you have kept that file in c:\\temp\\config.properties if you are using in your project then you can use class loader to load from project

Comment: `getAssets().openFd("config.properties").createOutputStream()` should return a FileOutputStream on the path of the file (look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075814/8633513) - The path don't seems to be the problem because in that case would get an exeption.

Comment: hi Terick I tried the snippet in my eclipse ,post that only I gave the solution.Can you debug and see whether config.properties are getting loaded properly

Comment: Basically your code should look similar to this
http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/

Comment: Okay I'm pretty sure now that it is an problem on the android file-system (the assets-folder my be not writeable?) - a self-written .properties file can be loaded sucessfully. Now the write operation thrwos an error. I will update the question.